# Attraction between 2 rigid bodies

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to make two rigid bodies attract one another. 
But I don't want them to attract the other rigid bodies.

In other terms I want in my scene :

- Rigid Bodies A and B attract one another and get closer and closer.
- Rigid Bodies C and D attract one another and get closer and closer.
- But A has no influence at all on C and D.
- B has no influence at all on C and D.
- C has no influence at all on A and B.
- D has no influence at all on A and B.

How coud I achieve this ?

Chears

Comment: If you don't have a problem with multiple layers you can put them onto separate layers and then just composite them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forces only have an effect on rigid bodies on the same Layer - so use separate layers for each set of independent objects and forces.

Essentially you need to do the following :

On one layer, create objects A and B. Create a 'Force' force field at the origin of object A (select object A, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and select 'Cursor to Selected', then Add/Force Field/Force) and parent it to object A. Create a 'Force' force field at the origin of object B and parent it to object B. Set each of the force fields to a *negative* strength (eg, -50). You should now find that A and B are drawn towards each other.

Swap to the next layer and repeat for C and D.

Running the animation (with both layers selected) should now result in two pairs of objects attracted to each other but not the other pair.

[image: result]

Comment: It just works ! Thank you ! Unfortunately 20 layers will not be enough for what I had in mind, but I learnt something new about force fields being limited to their layer only.

Comment: I hope this limitation will disappear with Blender 2.8's new layer system.